# How to set and get nested arrays in a PHP registry class

Tags: php

I have a PHP registry class with the methods

```
public static function get($key) {
    return isset(self::$vars[$key]) ? self::$vars[$key] : null;
}

public static function set($key, $value = null) {
        self::$vars[$key] = $value;
}
```

The problem is that i want to to be able to set and get nested arrays, like what i would do normally like this:

```
$array['a']['b'] = 'somevalue';
$myvalue = $array['a']['b'];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should look into magic functions.

Comment: OK, so what syntax do you have in mind for that? There's probably a way to make it work, but you need to know what you are aiming for.

Comment: how do i do that with magic functions?

Comment: Take a look at symfony's `ParameterBag` class.  As for the nesting, the most elegant way to do that with these 2 functions is to use a string delimiter and drill down on them.

Comment: If you are using the Registry with static methods and properties, you can just as well do `$registry = array();` and then use it from anywhere with `$GLOBALS['registry']`. There is no difference. Both is bad. But at least, you'd be able to use what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The array could be defined as public:

```
public static $vars;
```

And then you will be able to access directly:

```
ClassName::$vars['a']['b'] = 'somevalue';
$myvalue = ClassName::$vars['a']['b'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use references:

```
Storage::set("test", array('foo' => 'bar'));
$test = &Storage::get("test");
echo $test['foo']."\n"; // bar

$test['foo'] = "foobar";
$test2 = Storage::get("test");;
echo $test['foo']; // foobar
```

Also see [this example phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qjh-zgq).